# with oauth Is there a way to call my c# API after a user signs up to my application in an integrated workflow way

Tags: c#, angular, oauth

I have setup an angular app that uses a c# web api. When a new user signs up I want to create a workflow where immediately after I call into one of my api controller methods and add some logic, but only on sign up not all the time

Does anyone know the best way of doing this?